# Scrapy - url open error [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: scrapy, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to deploy a project in Osx (Osx El Capitan 10.11.6), but I get the following error.

> Deploying to project "webofscience" in
>   http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
>   Deploy failed:

Could they be administrator permissions ?, add some line in the host file ??

I can not think what I could do to solve it. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the error ??

source code: https://github.com/damlaozdemir/webofsciencescrapy

Console error

```
webofsciencescrapy-master sudo scrapyd-deploy local -p webofscience
Password:
Packing version 1518114723
Deploying to project "webofscience" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Deploy failed: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>
webofsciencescrapy-master
```

---

#### Solution:

I had 2 problems,

(1) The first one that my scrapyd installation was damaged. I threw the following error.

```
blablabla
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 63, in <module>
from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 38, in <module>
TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
```

exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
I solved it in this link https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473 summary

```
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo pip install --upgrade scrapy
sudo pip install --upgrade twisted
sudo pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
sudo pip install Twisted==16.4.1
```

(2) The second problem is 'Deploy failed: ', for this problem it's necessary run the command scrapyd (layer 8 problem).

Comment: Is `scrapyd` running? maybe run as administrator.

Comment: yes, I am tried with sudo, but nothing ... :(

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.